# Qemu can't load bios-256k.bin when running on Windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I was trying to test qemu on Windows OS and when I tried to start an ubuntu iso whith the following command:

> qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom .\ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -m 2048

Then I getting the following error:

> qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'

Qemu folder is set in Enviroment Varibles and the bios-256k.bin file is in the folder
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's your qemu command line?

Comment: I updated the question with the command line

Comment: When the problem is in finding the BIOS binary, it can be solved by adding 
"-L path_to_bios" to your qemu command line. But my test with other OSes didnt show same problem, even without using -L option and without having the BIOS binary in my PATH.

Comment: In Linux I can run it no problem, but in windows I'm always getting this error. I already tried to point to the bios wit the L argument, but the problem persists

Comment: I can only assume there is no file named exactly 'bios-256k.bin' or it is damaged. Copy it to your linux machine and try to run the same VM using exactly this BIOS file.

Comment: I was able to start an OS image with the `-L` path specified (not without it, which is why I was looking for solution), looks like a bug to me. Yours may be a different bug. Did you find something for your issue with a Google search? I guess it might not be the first page though. I can only suggest you to try and reinstall qemu at this point.

Comment: Also, if you tried to target directly specific BIOS with the `-L` switch, then it doesn't work. You have to specify path to the file, not the file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an option for bios file directory entry with `-L` switch. Your command should look like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom .\ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -m 2048 -L "C:\Program Files\qemu"
```

Of course in case your default qemu installation is in `C:\Program Files\qemu` and bios files are inside that directory. For some reason, qemu has a bug that doesn't search bios files in defined path and look for them in current working directory.

Edit: I found a bug report that mentions this issue. It also seems to be fixed in newest version. Anyway, here is the link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1915794

> This is a known and documented problem with a simple workaround: "Known issue: currently requires start from installation directory or -L option to specify the location of the firmware files."
>
> And it is already fixed in the newer installer.